# How to get rid of timestamps infront of Date, as Pandas adds time stamps to date columns after saving to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I am a student and i am learning pandas.

I have created excel file named Student_Record.xlsx(using microsoft excel)
[image: in this sheet, we have DOB and YOP columns, which does not have time stamp]

I wanted to create new file using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\Student_Record.xlsx")
df.head()
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\Output.xlsx",index=False)
```

I opened the file in pandas and saving the file back to excel with different name(file name = Output)

I saved the file back to Excel, but when i open the file(Output) on MS.Excel the columns(DOB and YOP)have time stamp attached to dates.

[image: this Out put file added Time stamp infront of Date]

Please let me know how to print only date?(I want Output file and its contents to look exactly like the original file)

Hope to get some help/support.
Thank you

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `DOB` and `Year of passing` columns are of `datetime` format before they are saved to Excel.  As a result, they got converted back to the datetime representation when saved to Excel.

If you want to retain its contents to look exactly like the original file in `dd-mm-YYYY` format, you can try converting these 2 columns to string format before saving to Excel. You can do it by:

```
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df['Year of passing'] = df['Year of passing'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```